# problems with td search in table using regex

Tags: php, regex

i've got problems with regex, please help.

My regex code for searching table -

```
/<table class="curr.*?">.*?<\/table>/s
```

How can i search TD in that table?

Comment: [Don't use regexes for parsing HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Then what u recommend for parsing html?

Comment: It depends on your exact use case, whether the HTML is user-provided, etc. but definitely use a library rather than trying to solve the problem yourself. http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ is one possibility.

Answer (score 0):

As someone before said:

> When you decide to use regular expressions to solve a problem, you end up having two problems :-)

Tidy + xPath will be my choice to do the job.